# Derivative, sensitivity and implicit function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have this implicit function $$y=f(x) \iff \sin(x+y)=k \sin(x), \quad$$ where $k>1$ is a constant.

I would like to know how a small variation in $x$ propagates on $y$.

I think I need to do an implicit differentiation but then it is not so clear to me how to solve the problem.

So the derivative of the LHS is

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\sin(x+y)) = \cos(x+y)(1+\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x})$$

and the derivative of the RHS is

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(k\sin(x)) = k\cos(x)$$

And solving for $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ gives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{k\cos(x)-\cos(x+y)}{\cos(x+y)}$$

and now how can I continue?

Thank you.

Comment: How about just rewriting this as $y=\sin^{-1}(k\sin(x)) - x$ and differentiating the right side?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I do not know how to explain it but I am not so comfortable with the inverse trigonometric functions... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the result you would like to obtain. First of all,
$$
dy = \left(\frac{k\cos{x}}{\cos(x+y)}-1\right)dx
$$
so the propagation of $dx$ on $dy$ depends on $x$ as well as on $y(x)$. You can make better if recall that $\cos^2(x+y) + k^2\sin^2x = 1$ which can help you to rewrite the denominator and obtain the dependence only on $x$.

Comment: +1, thank you, it was the dependency on y(x) that puzzles me a bit.

Comment: @uvts_cvs: note that in general this trick will not work and you will have $dy = f(x,y)dx$. What puzzled you?

Comment: I was puzzled because I was not expecting the full dependency on $x$ and $y(x)$ but you are obviously right.

Comment: Let's say I am interested at $x=0$ where we have $y=0$. How can I plug in these numbers into the $\frac{dy}{dx}$? I get $\frac{dy}{dx}=k-1$ and now how can I interpret this result? A small (how much small?) change in $x$ will be amplified by $k-1$?

Comment: I have an advise for you to open $\sin(x+y)$, denote $z = \sin y$ and find $z(x)$ if you like to deal with explicit dependencies. Note that for $x=0$ you have $y = \pi k$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your equation as:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{k\cos(x)}{\cos(x+y)}-1$$

Then notice that:

$$\cos(x+y) = \pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x+y)} = \pm \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)}$$

So:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\pm \frac{k\cos(x)}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)}}-1$$

Where the sign is determined by the sign of $\cos(x+y)$.